# Truncate string and replace with "X" Python Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df such as:

```
d = {'col1': [11111111, 2222222]]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
   col1  
0     11111111     
1     2222222
```

I need to remove everything before the first four characters and replace with something like "X" such that the new df would be

```
d = {'col1': [XXXX1111, XXX2222]]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
   col1  
0     XXXX1111     
1     XXX2222
```

New to python still and have been able to for example slice the last four characters. But have not been able to replace everything else with X's.

Also, strings can be different lengths. So the number of X's is dependent on the length of the string. That particularly is what has given me trouble. If they were all the same length this would be much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
df['col1'] = list(map(lambda l: 'X'*(l-4), df['col1'].astype(str).apply(len))) + df['col1'].astype(str).str[-4:]
```

- `map()` is to repeat `X` `n-4` times, where `n` is the length of each element in `col1`.
- `.str[-4:]` is to get the last 4 character in `col1` column

```
# print(df)

       col1
0  XXXX1111
1   XXX2222
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.str.replace()` with regex:

```
df.col1 = df.col1.astype(str).str.replace(
    r"^(.*)(.{4})$", lambda g: "X" * len(g.group(1)) + g.group(2)
)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
       col1
0  XXXX1111
1   XXX2222
```